# How do I get rid of a critter in my attic?

Tags: attic

The last two nights I have been woken up to scratching in my bedroom ceiling. It only seems to happen between 2 and 4am. But it drives me nuts and I can't sleep.

Are squirrels nesting in my attic? How do I get rid of them?

Comment: Forget the squirrel! We have a Mama rat! How do we get rid of her?

Comment: If the question was updated I would give it a + vote but the way it is it was confusing on how the accepted answer was talking about a rat when the question was about a squirl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **We have a Mama rat! How do we get rid of her?**

The usual procedure is

- Find out where it got in and block the entrance. Wire mesh (wire cloth) works if you get a size suited to the size of animal. Small mice can squeeze through tiny gaps.
- Put down several baited traps.

  - Check daily and keep resetting and rebaiting until all the visitors have been removed

There are several types of trap and of course you can always hire someone experienced or a reputable firm to do the work for you.

Rats are quite smart so you may have to try several types of trap and keep moving them around. Placement is important, you typically put them against the edges of spaces.